# A colon vs. A dash in a sentence

Tags: grammar, punctuation, colons, dashes

I came across this question while studying for the SAT.

After World War I, Percy Spencer was hired to work in the research _____ later known as Raytheon Manufacturing.

A) lab of American Applicance Company: (a colon)
B) lab of American Appliance Company-- (em dash)

Though the answer choice states that B) is the correct answer, it does not specify the reason why A) is not preferable over B).

I wonder if the usage of the colon in this sentence is correct. (As it sounds, to me, a little awkward to place a phrase like 'later known as --' after a colon.)

I'd appreciate it if you could enlighten me. Thank you.

Comment: A colon would announce what follows, like an arrow -> does. A comma works there, but a dash is good. To bring in a colon: "research lab of AAC: Raytheon Manufacturing."

Comment: As so often, this test question illustrates what is wrong with much multiple (in this case binary) choice testing.  Moreover, a reason should have been provided.  I agree with you.  The phrase at issue is parenthetic (like an aside, added on to explain to anyone not recognising the company name given that it now has a new name).  I personally prefer it to be bracketed, as in B, because then the closure of brackets renders the syntactic separation clearer.  But the use of the em dash is also a way of introducing a parenthetic remark/explanation.  So either would do.

Answer (score 1):

***later known as Raytheon Manufacturing*** can be imagined as a reduced relative clause (warning: grammar terms vary) — reduced from ***which was later known as Raytheon Manufacturing***:

> *After World War I, Percy Spencer was hired to work in the research lab of American Appliance Company, which was later known as Raytheon
> Manufacturing.*

There you can see that the relative clause is “nonrestrictive” (nonessential); you can leave it off. The em dash can take the place of the comma for the same effect.

*You can’t leave off what would follow a colon:

Answer (score 0):

- *After World War I, Percy Spencer was hired to work in the research lab of American Applicance Company (later known as Raytheon Manufacturing).*

This variant of the original shows that what follows the punctuation mark in question is a (terminal) non-defining parenthetical (additional information [not used to point to / identify a specific example] whose removal does not affect the grammaticality of the matrix sentence).

Colons are not used to offset such parentheticals, but a comma, dash or brackets would work well. For a terminal parenthetical such as this, one comma or dash is (but, as here, two brackets are) required.

Dashes are even more catholic in their applications than colons. And colons may be used to explain from first principles, clarify, expand on, emphasise, provide evidence for the preceding sentence; to ask for clarification ... and to introduce a list, or an example or consequence. Indeed,

- *After World War I, Percy Spencer was hired to work in the research lab of American Applicance Company: this company was later known as Raytheon Manufacturing).*

is licensed if this is in response to 'What connection is there between Percy Spencer and Raytheon Manufacturing?' to show an extended explanation. Some would prefer a semicolon. The full sentence (independent clause) following the colon seems to sit more happily than the deleted equivalent used in the original.

Answer (score 0):

A colon is often used to indicate that what follows is a list of things included in a previously mentioned set.

> To sew a button on you will need these items:  needle, thread, button, and optionally a thimble.

Sometimes a colon can introduce a thought that "flows" from or completes a previous thought.

> When we reached the summit, it was glorious: the sun was setting in the west and the ice looked as though it was on fire.

The em-dash on the other hand often introduces a piece of info that doesn't really flow from or complete the previous thought, it just adds something extra.

> He worked as a copy editor at a small newspaper called *The Towntalk* — later known as the *Allentown Gaper Delay*.